# sys.stdout.write and sys.stdout.flush leave characters behind

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a counter that ticks down from 1,000,000 to 0 in increments of 100,000 per second and displays this on one line, updating each second.

However, the below code prints an extra zero at the end:

```
counter = 1000000

while counter > 0:
    sys.stdout.write("%s\r" % counter)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    counter -= 100000
    time.sleep(1)
```

I get the output (each writing over the previous line):

```
1000000
9000000
8000000
7000000
6000000
...
```

The script stops correctly at the end. When I replace `\r` with `\n` it prints the numbers correctly, but obviously I want it to refresh rather than create a new line each time.

Comment: That's not Python's fault, it's just the way your terminal works. You could use control sequences to clear to the end of the line, but the simple, portable way is to use formatting to ensure you have spaces that will overwrite unwanted leftover characters.

Comment: BTW, thete's no need to use `sys.stdout.write` for this. You can use the `print` function, even in Python 2.6+.

Comment: `\r` just moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line. It does not erase already printed output.

Answer (score 2):

Last character is left from the first line, as a workaround you could overwrite it manually:

```
while counter > 0:
    sys.stdout.write(str(counter).ljust(7) + "\r")
    counter -= 100000
    time.sleep(1)
```